# Ajax contact form animation

Tags: jquery, ajax

My contact form seems doesnt works well, its almost everything ok, sends email, checking inputs, but not showing any animation with those pictures.. After sending email i wonder why ? its a syntax error or what ? i just inserted a contactform

```
<a name="contactForm"></a>
  <div id="contact-query-form">
        <h3>Contact form</h3>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" size="28">
        <label>Company name</label>
         <input id="company_name" type="text" name="company_name" size="28">
         <label>Email</label>
          <input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="28">
         <label>Phone</label>
          <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" size="28">
           <label>Question:</label>
           <textarea id="question" name="question" ></textarea>
           <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="<? echo CURRENT_LANG; ?>">
            <button type="button" id="send">Send</button></div>
           <div><img id="contact_form_img" src="<? echo THEME_DIR; ?>/img/contact-form.png" width="369"  alt="" /></div>
                    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                            jQuery('#send').click(function() {
                                var name = jQuery("#name").val();
                                var company_name = jQuery("#company_name").val();
                                var email = jQuery("#email").val();
                                var phone = jQuery("#phone").val();
                                var question = jQuery("#question").val();
                                var re = /^(([^<>()[]\.,;:s@"] (.[^<>()[]\.,;:s@"] )*)|(". "))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9] .) [a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                                if (!email) {
                                    alert('Enter email address!');
                                    return false;
                                } else if (!re.test(email)) {
                                    alert('Email is invalid!');
                                    return false;
                                }

                                if (!question) {
                                    alert('Enter your question.');
                                    return false;
                                }
                                jQuery.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: '<? echo THEME_DIR; ?>/inc/inc-mail.php',
                                    data: {'name': name, 'company_name': company_name, 'email': email, 'phone': phone, 'question': question},
                                    success: function() {
                                        var url = window.location.href;
                                        if (url.indexOf('#contactForm') != -1) {
                                      var a_top = jQuery('a[name="contactForm"]').offset().top;
                                            jQuery('html,body').animate({'scrollTop': a_top}, 0);
                                            jQuery("#contact-query-form").hide();
                                            jQuery("#contact_form_img").attr('src', '<? echo THEME_DIR; ?>/img/contact-form-sent.png ?>');
                                            setTimeout(function() {
                                                jQuery("#contact-query-form").fadeIn(1200);
                                                jQuery("#contact_form_img").attr('src', '<? echo THEME_DIR; ?>/img/contact-form.png ?>');
                                            }, 5000);
                                        }

                                    }

                                });
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
```

Comment: what do you get if you console.log a_top in the success callback? I also can't see a 'a' tag with a name of contactForm??

Comment: try `location.hash==='#contactForm'` instead of `location.href`